# Read variables from file and loop through them in bash

Tags: bash

I have a text file containing variables like this:

```
lane1_pair1="file1"
lane1_pair2="file2"
lane2_pair1="file3"
lane2_pair2="file4"
...
```

I'd like to loop through the variables and concatenate all of them in a single file. I am applying the loop as:

```
. variables
for (( n=1; n<=no_lanes; n++ )) {

        cat $"lane"${n}_pair1 >> "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
        cat $"lane"${n}_pair2 >> "$sampleID"_cat2.fq
}

"$sampleID"_cat1.fq > fq_align_1
"$sampleID"_cat2.fq > fq_align_2
```

The problem here is that, cat command does not work because instead of replacing the `"laneX_pairY"` with its value, treat it as a string. I was wondering if anyone here has any idea about this.

Comment: I'm not sure about several elements of this: where are the `no_lanes`, `lane`, and `sampleID` variables defined?  What are the bottom two lines trying to accomplish?  What do you want the final file output to look like?

Comment: The last two line basically put the concatenated contents into the fq_align that will be passed to the next argument.

Comment: So in those lines you're attempting to read from a file and put the result in a variable, is that right?

Comment: Thats true. I have a variable file that contains the value for `no_lanes`, `lane` and `sampleID`. The problem here is by looping over variable, I cant concatenate the contents of each variable as they are being treated as strings. The machine  throughs this error:

Comment: `cat: lane1_pair1: No such file or directory
cat: lane1_pair2: No such file or directory
cat: lane2_pair1: No such file or directory
cat: lane2_pair2: No such file or directory
cat: lane3_pair1: No such file or directory
cat: lane3_pair2: No such file or directory
cat: lane4_pair1: No such file or directory
cat: lane4_pair2: No such file or directory
cat: lane5_pair1: No such file or directory
cat: lane5_pair2: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, the problem is you're looping through variables that are named like an array but aren't one.  Then you're in the position of trying to evaluate the contents of the variable name created from your other indexing variable, which is a recipe for messy code that breaks easily.  I recommend making actual arrays of file names from your `variables` file:

```
p1_files=($(grep 'pair1' variables | cut -d '=' -f 2))
p2_files=($(grep 'pair2' variables | cut -d '=' -f 2))

for f in "${p1_files[@]}"; do
    cat "${f//\"/}" >> "$sampleID"_cat1.fq
done

for f in "${p2_files[@]}"; do
    cat "${f//\"/}" >> "$sampleID"_cat2.fq
done
```

I'm not sure how you want your `fq_align_n` variables to be, but you can read the file contents to variables using:

```
fq_align_1=$(cat "$sampleID"_cat1.fq)
fq_align_2=$(cat "$sampleID"_cat2.fq)
```

Or just skip the file creation altogether and build the variables incrementally in the loops.